# JQuery .addClass() with less mixins

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, less

I have a JQuery function that adds classes to an element. I want to use the http://daneden.me/animate/ animation package. To do this, I needed to add two classes, "animated" and "*animation type example*", to my element. However, instead of adding a simple animation class, I wanted to change animate.css to animate.less so that I could pass in mixin parameters. But the JQuery addClass() function doesn't recognize my code as being valid.

**ex]** .animated{*//effects*} has already been changed to: .animated(@duration, @delay){*//effects*}

The code that works without mixins:

```
function waterColorAnmiation(){
    $("#stroke1").addClass("animated fadeInUp");
}
```

What I've tried in order to use mixins for @duration & @delay:

```
function waterColorAnmiation(){
    $("#stroke1").addClass("animated(1, 3) fadeInUp");
}
```

Please let me know if you have suggestions or if there is a much easier way to accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: or try to use css keyframes instead ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? I am using keyframes for the animation but I need them to be triggered at a certain point. Take a look at my jsfiddle below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that, you need to define a new class for the mixin `animated(1, 3)` then use it like
In your less file

```
.animated13 {
    .animated(1, 3);
}
```

then

```
$("#stroke1").addClass("animated13 fadeInUp");
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, however it still doesn't seem to like this. Please check out my JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/B5zCu/301/) and see what I mean. The less nested class effect works when I place them directly within the css... but when I use JQuery to add the classes, it doesn't work. And I need this to work since I want to have a trigger for the jquery.

Comment: looks like you a selector error http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UnQ22/1/ ... `someDiv` instead of `somediv` in the jQuery selector

Comment: After trying that version and two new ones several times... I finally got it working. I am thinking it was either just a syntax error or an actual issue with the minified animate.css files!